# How to do random sampling within interval with given interval value?

Tags: python

How can I do random sampling within interval with given interval?
For example, I want to do single random sampling between 1 to 10 but with each interval is 0.5. So when I do the sampling, it will give me value for example 5.5 or 2 or 8.5.

I have tried with
    np.random.random_integers(1,10)
but this just give me integers value.
Your help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: How small is your step (ex, 0.5 in your question) likely to be and how wide is the interval (ex, 1-10 in your question) in a real situation? You'll probably have to write something yourself to get a range of real numbers, which could get very large even for small intervals with a small enough increment (say 1-5 with step 0.0001).

Comment: Why not simply `random.randint(2, 20) / 2.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own function which scales, generates a random integer, and then unscales.

```
from math import floor, ceil
from random import randint

def random_step(low, high, step):
    low_scaled = ceil(float(low)/step)
    high_scaled = floor(float(high)/step)
    return randint(low_scaled, high_scaled) * step

print random_step(3.0, 8.5, 0.5) # 4.5
```

The output will always be a multiple of `step`.

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :). It really works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linspace` from the `numpy` library. Here is an example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.linspace(0.5, 10, 20)
array([  0.5,   1. ,   1.5,   2. ,   2.5,   3. ,   3.5,   4. ,   4.5,
         5. ,   5.5,   6. ,   6.5,   7. ,   7.5,   8. ,   8.5,   9. ,
         9.5,  10. ])
>>> range_of_numbers = numpy.linspace(0.5, 10, 20)
>>> random_number = numpy.random.choice(range_of_numbers, size=1)
>>> print random_number
[ 9.5]
```

The result set of `linspace` is in an array, but you can easily work with that further if need be. Here is some more documentation on using [`linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace).

---

**EDIT**

Another option is to use Pylab's `frange` library. It's a wrapper around `matplotlib`, but worth looking into for the solution you are trying to achieve. Here's an example of using `frange`:

```
>>> import pylab
>>> pylab.frange(0.5,10,0.5)
array([  0.5,   1. ,   1.5,   2. ,   2.5,   3. ,   3.5,   4. ,   4.5,
         5. ,   5.5,   6. ,   6.5,   7. ,   7.5,   8. ,   8.5,   9. ,
         9.5,  10. ])
```

Here's some more documentation around [`frange`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.frange).

---

**Additional Notes**

While you could use `arange`, keep in mind that it leads to floating point errors. The NumPy documentation recommends using `linspace` to avoid the floating point errors. Also, `arange` and `linspace` have different APIs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciated it. Can I use numpy.linspace with the parameters have been determined before? I tried to determine low=1, high=10, size=20, and then I try numpy.linspace(low,high,num=size), but it doesn't work

Comment: It works. I made some mistakes on my formula. Sorry and thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome! An explanation of the downvote would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by an explanation of the downvote? Sorry, I am newbie in this forum

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
from random import randrange

random_number = randrange(2,21)*.5
```